# Show Tooltip for Angular (ng2-tooltip-directive) only when the value is not undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ng2-tooltip-directive

I'm using [Tooltip for Angular (ng2-tooltip-directive)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tooltip-directive) to show tooltips in my application.

Taking as an example the following code, how can I hide tooltips each time the `title` is undefined?

```
//HTML
<div tooltip="{{title}}"></div>

//TS
export class Component {
    title: string = undefined
}
```

Note: For this case, the tooltip is being shown without any text on it.

Moreover in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwvq2s) you have an full workable example

Answer (score 2):

```
<span [tooltip]="errorMessage" [display]="showTooltip" content-type="template" placement="right" show-delay="100" hide-delay="500">
```

there is a display attribute for the ng2 tooltip. You can use that. Here I have assigned a boolean variable `showTooltip` to the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use *ngIf

```
<ng-container *ngIf="title">
    <div tooltip="{{title}}"></div>
<ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="title == null">
     <div></div>
<ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times to hide the tooltip with a condition in `ng2-tooltip-directive`. They are providing the element selection and other features in Pro version. So it can be done in pro version.

For Angular material design there is other good tooltip libraries available.

Note: If you are iterating the items then using `*ngIf title and tooltip=""` is not recommended as we are duplicating all the code.

You can use `ngbTooltip` instead, if you are using **bootstrap** with your project:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

`npm module`

```
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

imports: [
  ....
  NgbModule,
  ....
]
```

`.html`

```
<ng-template #TooltipContent>
 <div>This file belongs to <b>
  {{file.owner.name}}</b>
 </div>
</ng-template> 

<div *ngFor="let file of files">
  .....
  <div [ngbTooltip]="file.owner.name ? TooltipContent : ''">
    .....
    .....
  </div>
  .....
  .....
</div>
```

In the above example, the tooltip show only if the file has owner.